# Which KYC solution providers are used by Bitcoin companies?

Tags: services, aml, know-your-customer

I am wondering which Know Your Client solution providers are used by Bitcoin companies?

Answer (score 1):

- [Jumio](https://www.jumio.com/) is used by a few companies, including SnapSwap, CoinMKT, etc. Their notable products include [NetVerify](https://www.jumio.com/netverify/) and [BISON](https://www.jumio.com/bison/).
- [miiCard](http://www.miicard.com/) is used by [Bylls and Bittylicious](http://www.miicard.com/blog/201403/whats-new-use-your-miicard-these-bitcoin-sites).
- [Sphonic](http://www.sphonic.com/) is used by [Bitnet](http://www.thepaypers.com/cryptocurrencies-bitcoin-virtual-currencies/bitnet-technologies-partners-sphonic-for-kyc-aml-services/757197-39).